# Typescript prototyping of a definition file

Tags: typescript, prototype

I'm learning Typescript, and I want to take advantage of prototyping. I'm also using an external library which has a typings file.

So far, this works.

```
// main.ts
declare class Foo {}

interface Foo {
  bar(): void;
}

Foo.prototype.bar = function() {}
```

However, the declaration is in a different file, so when I try this it doesn't work.

foo.d.ts:

```
declare class Foo {}
```

main.ts:

```
interface Foo {
  bar(): void;
}

Foo.prototype.bar = function() {}
```

main.ts: TS6133: 'Foo' is declared but never used.
main.ts: TS2339: Property 'bar' does not exist on type 'Foo'.

Is there a compile flag I'm missing or something? How do I get this to compile when in separate files?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [module augmentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html#module-augmentation):

```
// main.ts
import { Foo } from "./foo";

Foo.prototype.bar = function() {}
```